# Choices for "What type of question do you have?" are too vague

Tags: discussion, ask-question-wizard-2018

The Software Recommendations Stack Exchange has lately been overwhelmed with off-topic questions that belong on Stack Overflow or Super User largely due to the [Ask Question Wizard](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/recent-proliferation-of-how-to-code-questions-superuser-questions) on Stack Overflow. I think by making the text in the wizard, we can make it clearer what is on topic for what site.

[image: Screenshot of guided question]

It's important to get this page right and not rely on the additional description on the next page, because at that point they're probably just seeing "does this site sound vaguely what I'm looking for" and not thinking as much about whether another site would be a better fit. We can't rely on the /on-topic page, because that's a lot to read and people are lazy and at they're point they're not likely to go back to the wizard.

Firstly, I think the "I need" and "I have" makes it harder to read and compare the options and doesn't make it any friendlier.

"I have a question about some code" sounds like you're looking at some code, and you want to know what it does. It doesn't surprise me that many people debugging don't end up picking this choice. I think the text from the Stack Overflow tour would be a significant improvement. We could just say "Specific programming problems, software algorithms, coding techniques, or software development tools"

"I need a software recommendation" and "The Software Recommendations community is here to help you find software that matches your requirements. Tip: Have your requirements, budget, and operating system ready when asking on Software Recommendations." doesn't say what kind of "software" is on topic. Software Recs is about finding a piece of (application) software or software library that meets a list a requirements that you've defined - not algorithms or code. In contrast, some recently asked questions are about:

- Comparing two algorithms: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/65901/calculating-tree-height-efficiency-algorithm
- Looking for a "plugin" for React: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/65906/how-to-make-interactive-image-react-native
- Programming question: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/65886/how-to-connect-query-postman-to-react-native
- Asking about whether this programming software meets their needs: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/65880/laravel-and-ionic-4-a-practical-combination-for-one-code-base-for-web-app-and-mo
- Installation issues: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/65848/phpstorm-codeception-installation-issues

Some of these questions are technically asking for "software recommendations", since code is software - I mean, it's not a hardware recommendation. We could rewrite this choice as "Finding an application or library that meets a list of requirements".

I think the option for Super User should be moved higher. It seems that people often have a piece of software they want to troubleshoot, but then think of that as looking for a "software recommendation" that would solve their problem. In addition, Super User is a significantly larger community than Software Recommendations, and would be better able to handle the inflow of questions.

In all, I suggest changing the choices to something like the following:

- Specific programming problems, software algorithms, coding techniques, or software development tools
- Homework coding problem
- Troubleshooting a (non-programming) software or hardware problem
- Finding an application or library that meets your needs
- Hardware recommendation

(I'm not familiar with Hardware Recommendations, so I don't know what exactly is on topic there.)

It's a lot more to read, but I think it's worth it so that people are better informed about what is on topic for a site and are less likely to end up on the wrong site and get their question closed.

Comment: "Overwhelmed" does look like an apt description: looking at the new questions feed right now, I see 3 on-topic questions out of 15, in a span of four hours.

Answer (score 5):

I think we already gave this feedback regarding the wizard at some point. It should be saying something like (my proposal):

*I need a recommendation about which tool or library to use, or where to find it.*

Regarding hardware recommendations, they aren't really on-topic anywhere. Help trouble-shooting PC hardware may be on topic at https://superuser.com/. I'm not familiar with that site (maybe questions along the line of "what PC hardware spec do I need in order to run x" are on-topic?).

Help trouble-shooting electronics, embedded systems or microcontroller firmware is on topic at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/. However, "what to use/where to buy" shopping recommendations are explicitly off-topic there.

Comment: There actually is a (beta) Stack Exchange site called Hardware Recommendations: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: "where to find it" may be off-topic - see https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2865/can-i-ask-about-finding-installers-and-drivers